# Writing arrays to dictionary list

Tags: csv, python-3.x

To begin thanks a million for reading my post and any information you may offer to begin with.

I am trying to print to a csv file and have everything working until it comes to the printing. I have tryed to print a simple dictionary list and that works perfectly and when I input my array names it is not coming back with an error so logic says I am doing that right but when I trying print it to a file it will only print the first items in the array list and it prints it out 3 times. I am dead sure that I am making a stupid mistake but can't seem to drum up an answer for it online. For the record this is not a homework assignment this is just something I am trying to learn on my own.

```
    import csv

n = 0

product = ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Whiskey']
item = ['Lager', 'Red', 'Bells']
size = ['Pint', 'Bottle', 'Single']
price = [5.50, 17.50, 5.50]


receipt_dict = {'Product': product[n],
                'Item': item[n],
                'Size': size[n],
                'Price': price[n]}

headings = {'Product',
            'Item',
            'Size',
            'Price'}

receipt = open('dict.csv', 'w')
w = csv.DictWriter(receipt, fieldnames=headings, dialect='excel')
w.writeheader()

while len(product) != n:
    w.writerow(receipt_dict)
    n += 1

receipt.close()
```

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I would be greatful.

Kind regards

Matthew

Comment: you are initializing `receipt_dict` with values and not changing those values. ie `product[n] == 'Beer'` if `n = 1` at the beginning of the code. jsut because you are iterating n, does not mean you are iterating the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepping through your code, here is what happens:

> ```
> n = 0
> ```

Create a variable named `n` and initialize it to `0`.

> ```
> product = ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Whiskey']
> item = ['Lager', 'Red', 'Bells']
> size = ['Pint', 'Bottle', 'Single']
> price = [5.50, 17.50, 5.50]
> ```

Create some more variables and initialize them.  So far so good.  (although I would design the data structure differently, this is not yet an error)

> ```
> receipt_dict = {'Product': product[n],
>                 'Item': item[n],
>                 'Size': size[n],
>                 'Price': price[n]}
> ```

Here you create a variable named `receipt_dict` and initialize it to a new dict object.  This expression is evaluated at this time.  Since at this time, `n == 0`, the values here will be the first element of each of your lists.

That is, this has the same effect as writing the following:

```
receipt_dict = {'Product': 'Beer',
                'Item': 'Lager',
                'Size': 'Pint',
                'Price': 5.50}
```

> ...
>
> ```
> while len(product) != n:
>     w.writerow(receipt_dict)
>     n += 1
> ```

Since `len(product)` is `3`, your loop will execute three iterations.  Each iteration you write the value of `receipt_dict`.  Since `receipt_dict` has not changed since it was created, and since the loop does not change it, it will be the same each time.

This is why you see the same row three times.

One way to fix it is to make a function to create the dict:

```
def create_item(a_number):
    return {'Product': product[a_number],
                    'Item': item[a_number],
                    'Size': size[a_number],
                    'Price': price[a_number]}
```

Then in your loop, use the function:

```
while n < len(product):
    receipt_dict = create_item(n)
    w.writerow(receipt_dict)
    n += 1
```

Note that I wrote the loop condition in the more idiomatic manner.  It would be even more idiomatic in Python to write it:

```
for n in range( len(product) ):
    receipt_dict = create_item(n)
    w.writerow(receipt_dict)
```

Comment: you would need to set those lists (`product,item,size,price') as global variables to access them, right?

Comment: @RNar Yes, the way I wrote that function.  They already are global lists in the OP's script as posted.

Comment: Thanks a million @dsh

Comment: @dsh Thanks a million took a little messing around with but your suggestion worked a dream. Again I tried to vote you up but don't have enough reputation yet for it to work. Again thanks a million mate.

Comment: @MatthewSwart You're welcome.  You can still accept my answer (the checkmark) even if you can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix involves moving your code that relies on the changing `n` value to inside the loop that changes `n`.  If `receipt_dict` is inside the loop, it will be re-evaluated and change in the way you are expecting it to.

Also note that `headings` has been changed from a set to a list because sets are unordered and those headings would therefore print out in an arbitrary order that you do not control.  When `headings` is a list, the order of the columns will be exactly in the order you defined them.

```
import csv

n = 0

product = ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Whiskey']
item = ['Lager', 'Red', 'Bells']
size = ['Pint', 'Bottle', 'Single']
price = [5.50, 17.50, 5.50]


headings = ['Product',
            'Item',
            'Size',
            'Price']

receipt = open('dict.csv', 'w')
w = csv.DictWriter(receipt, fieldnames=headings, dialect='excel')
w.writeheader()

while len(product) != n:
    receipt_dict = {'Product': product[n],
                    'Item': item[n],
                    'Size': size[n],
                    'Price': price[n]}
    w.writerow(receipt_dict)
    n += 1

receipt.close()
```

A more Pythonic way to write your code:

```
import csv

product = ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Whiskey']
item = ['Lager', 'Red', 'Bells']
size = ['Pint', 'Bottle', 'Single']
price = [5.50, 17.50, 5.50]

headings = ['Product', 'Item', 'Size', 'Price']

with open('dict.csv', 'w') as receipt:
    writer = csv.writer(receipt, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(headings)
    for row in zip(product, item, size, price):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here we use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop and we use `zip` to zip together our four lists.  We're also using a simple `csv.writer` with headings instead of a DictWriter (this makes for simpler code in since we're starting with lists and not dictionaries).  We're also using a `with` block (a context manager) to open our file which will ensure it is always closed as expected, even if an exception occurs.

A probably even more Pythonic approach would be to replace our for loop with a single `writerows` statement, passing in our zipped lists iterable.

Replace this:

```
for row in zip(product, item, size, price):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

With this:

```
writer.writerows(zip(product, item, size, price))
```

Comment: Thanks Trey for the input... Tried to give you a thumbs but still need more reputation. Again thanks.